# How to adjust the date set through UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, xcode, calendar, uidatepicker

I'm using `UIDatePicker` and able to show the date that the user chooses from `UIDatePicker`.
I want to adjust the date and show the next/previous date by clicking some buttons, but I don't know how I can adjust the `UIDatePicker` date.

Please help me. Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var InputTextField: UITextField!

    private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        InputTextField.inputView = datePicker


    }


    @objc func viewTapped (gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }


    @objc func dateChanged (datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

        InputTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

//From here, it's new
    @IBAction func RightArrow(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let date = datePicker!.date
             if let modifiedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) {
               datePicker!.date = modifiedDate
            InputTextField.inputView = datePicker
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: I added my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is to update the UIDatePicker with the date you want, you can simply set the date property of UIDatePicker.

```
let date = datePicker.date
if let modifiedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) {
   datePicker.date = modifiedDate
   InputTextField.inputView = datePicker
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

   InputTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker!.date)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What if I want to add one day to the date that was selected through UIDatePicker? 
For example, the date "December 4th" is selected with UIDatePicker. I want to create a button that can add one day to the selected date (Dec4) so that I can show "December5th" by clicking a button in this case.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Do try the snipper in your button action and accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just added your code under the UIButton function, but the app crushed... (I updated my code↑)
```

    @IBAction func RightArrow(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let date = datePicker!.date
             if let modifiedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) {
               datePicker!.date = modifiedDate
            InputTextField.inputView = datePicker
    }

Comment: What was the exception occurred?

Comment: Xcode says, "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".
it also says "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: I tried the same snippet in the question and it worked fine only.

Comment: When i run the app, Xcode shows, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CalendarChallenge3.ViewController GoToNextDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8f827081f0' "

Comment: What is GoToNextDate here?

Comment: It was something that I created before, but I deleted it long time ago, so I cannot find it anymore. but maybe it still exists somewhere and disturbs this app..??

Comment: Search the project for GoToNextDate and remove references if there is any. Probably, it should have been an outlet connection you previously had for your button.

Comment: i was able to find and delete it! thank you!
However, when I click the right arrow, the adjusted date is not shown in the input textfield. Could you help me with this as well? I appreciate your help so much

Comment: I've updated the answer. Do try the snipper in your button action and accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I needed to add "view.endEditing(true)" at the end, but it worked!!! thank you so much!!